# Merge an associative array with comma if one index is same and other is different

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [field] => new
            [value] => pqr
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [field] => test
            [value] => abc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [field] => test
            [value] => xyz
        )

)
```

Now I want to merge this array with field name with id and value will be comma separated. So my new array will look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [field] => new
            [value] => pqr
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14,17
            [field] => test
            [value] => abc,xyz
        )
)
```

Can we do this with any php inbuilt function.

Comment: Instead of concatenating the values with a comma, would you accept them being stored in arrays of their own? as in `'id' => [14, 17]`. This is a more normalized end product which makes more sense to me, but it really depends on how you are going to use the data.

Comment: Yes, that will also work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any built in function to do this, but it's pretty trivial with a simple foreach loop.

### String Concatenation Approach

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array1 as $arr) {
    
    $field = $arr['field'];
    $id = $arr['id'];
    $value = $arr['value'];
    
    //we use $field as $new_array keys so we can combine values
    if(!array_key_exists($field, $new_array)) {
        
        //key doesn't exist in new array, so create it
        $new_array[$field] = $arr;
        
    } else {
    
        //key exists in new array, append new values
        $new_array[$field]['id'] .= ",{$id}";
        $new_array[$field]['value'] .= ",{$value}";
    
    }
    
}

//reset array keys back to sequential
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
```

Output of `$new_array` would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [field] => new
            [value] => pqr
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14,17
            [field] => test
            [value] => abc,xyz
        )

)
```

### Normalized Array Approach

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($array1 as $arr) {
    
    $field = $arr['field'];
    $id = $arr['id'];
    $value = $arr['value'];
    
    //we use $field as $new_array keys so we can combine values
    if(!array_key_exists($field, $new_array)) {
        
        //key doesn't exist in new array, so create it
        $new_array[$field] = ['id' => [$id], 'field' => $field, 'value' => [$value]];
        
    } else {
    
        //key exists in new array, append new values
        $new_array[$field]['id'][] = $id;
        $new_array[$field]['value'][] = $value;
    
    }
    
}

//reset array keys back to sequential
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
```

Output of `$new_array` would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                )

            [field] => new
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => pqr
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 17
                )

            [field] => test
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => abc
                    [1] => xyz
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks GrumpyCrouton. This  is working as expected.